# Only last element of file list being outputted with json.dump in python

Tags: python, json, list, file, object

Tried the same thing with 2 simple lists - `list1 = [1,2,3]` and `list2 =['a','b','c']` and the code works fine.

I'm extracting file information from both `.json` files and a `.list` files and appending that data to `json_data` and `tables_data` lists respectively.

I need to produce the following output format:

```
{
   "item1": {
       "json_data": "jsonfile1",
       "list_data": "listfile1"
   },
   "item2": {
       "json_data": "jsonfile2",
       "list_data": "listfile2"
   }
}
```

However, my code is only printing out the information from the last files in both `json_data` and `tables_data` for some reason despite appending the new information. I've also checked the lengths of both of these lists so it looks like the info has appended correctly too.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
json_files = []
table_files = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            json_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        if file.endswith(".list"):
            table_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))

    json_data = []
    for i in json_files:
        with open(i) as f:
            json_data.append(json.load(f))

    table_data = []
    for i in table_files:
        with open(i) as f:
            table_data.append([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]) 

    my_dict = {
        subdir: {
            "json_data": j,
            "table_data": t,
        } 
        for (j, t) in zip(json_data, table_data)
    }

with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_dict, f, indent=2)
```

Any idea on what is wrong here and what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the result of the last iteration to the output file. So you're getting only that info in the output. `my_dict` is getting re-written in each iteration.

You need to append to a list of `my_dict`s to save all the results.

```
json_files = []
table_files = []

my_dicts = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            json_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        if file.endswith(".list"):
            table_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))

    json_data = []
    for i in json_files:
        with open(i) as f:
            json_data.append(json.load(f))

    table_data = []
    for i in table_files:
        with open(i) as f:
            table_data.append([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f])

    my_dict = {
        subdir: {
            "json_data": j,
            "table_data": t,
        }
        for (j, t) in zip(json_data, table_data)
    }
    # save the result of this iteration
    my_dicts.append(my_dict)

with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    # write complete output to output file
    json.dump(my_dicts, f, indent=2)
```